# Trying to replace one fragment with another

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to replace a fragment with another at an onItemClick method.
This is what I am trying:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        TipoRestaurante rteActual = (TipoRestaurante) adapter.getItem(position);
        String msg = "Has elegido el tipo " + rteActual.getNombre_tipo();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Fragment newFragment = new TabFragmentComer();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();


        transaction.replace(R.id.containerView, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);


        transaction.commit();


    }
```

But I am getting an exception:

```
09-28 23:51:02.310  14895-14895/com.solinpromex.elpasojuarezexperience E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.solinpromex.elpasojuarezexperience, PID: 14895
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d009b (com.solinpromex.elpasojuarezexperience:id/containerView) for fragment TabFragmentComer{42909b40 #1 id=0x7f0d009b}
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am arriving to the current fragment from an activity, like this:

```
if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_comer) {
                     FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                     xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragmentComerTiposRestaurante()).commit();
                 }
```

Any help is welcome

EDIT: MainActivity xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/rojomodesto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:title="El Paso - Juárez Experience" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        >



    <FrameLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/containerView">
     </FrameLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/shitstuff"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
        android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
        />



    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can u pls post xml layout?

Comment: Xml layout where R.id.containerView is?

Comment: @RajeshJadav, you mean xml from the activity or from the current fragment?

Comment: The activity layout which contains the containerView

Comment: @RajeshJadav, just inserted in my question.

Comment: @Nanoc, just inserted in my question.

Comment: OnItemClick is in activity or fragment?!!

Comment: @SaeedEntezari , just inserted in my question.

Comment: @SaeedEntezari, it is on current fragment

Comment: you should move it to the activity. you cannot access the activities layout in fragment

Comment: No view found for id 0x7f0d009b (com.solinpromex.elpasojuarezexperience:id/containerView)


Please make sure , activity where you are arriving will also have the container view. as you can see in the exception, the containerview is not found

Comment: @SaeedEntezari, there is a ListView in the fragment, how could I move the onItemClick method to the activity? I am using other fragments in the app with ListViews

Comment: try to use getChildFragmentManager instead of getFragmentManager

Comment: Ill tell you in the answer.

Comment: @RajeshJadav, I will try now with getChildFragmentManager

Comment: @RajeshJadav, same exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fragment should have an interface in it as follows:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public MyFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = ...;
        return view;
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        TipoRestaurante rteActual = (TipoRestaurante) adapter.getItem(position);
        String msg = "Has elegido el tipo " + rteActual.getNombre_tipo();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Fragment newFragment = new TabFragmentComer();    

        if(mListener != null){
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(newFragment);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Fragment fragment);
    }

}
```

Your activity should implement that interface:

```
MyActivity extends Activity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener{
//your activity methods...

@Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Fragment fragment) {
         //here you have that fragment and can change it with transactions
         FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transaction.replace(R.id.containerView, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

---

**To pass objects to the other fragment:**

If the fragment is just the fragment you are creating above as newFragment you can add arguments to it as follows:

```
Fragment newFragment = new TabFragmentComer();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("myIntLabel", 2);
args.putString("myStringLabel", "my sample string");
//and you can add all you want to that bundle like this
newFragment.setArguments(args);
```

Then in your fragment onCreateView or onCreate method you can get that bundle like this:

```
...
Bundle args = getArguments();
int myInt = args.getInt("myIntLabel", (int defaultValue)); // returns 2
int myString  = args.getString("myStringLabel", (String defaultString)); // returns "my sample string"
```

And if you are not creating your fragment in this fragment you can add another argument to that interface method as `Bundle args` and add that bundle to your fragment where you create like this: `fragment.setArguments(args)`

Comment: Thank you Saeed, I will try your proposal just now.

Comment: @mvasco you are welcome. You can add this to all your fragments and handle the all transactions in your activity.

Comment: I have a warning at line:FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

Comment: What is the warning? Does is crash?

Comment: No, I cannot run it yet. It says: Error:(95, 80) error: incompatible types
required: android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction
found:    android.app.FragmentTransaction

Comment: But I have this as import: import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

Comment: Change getFragmentManager() to getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: It works, there is now another exception but due to the end fragment...thank you Saeed, this is a master lesson for me

Comment: may I ask you now a short question??? How can I pass a variable to the new fragment?

Comment: how could I use this interface to pass an object value from the first fragment to the second?

Comment: @mvasco you are welcome and the code is added to the answer

Comment: Thank you @Saeed, I am always getting a JavaNullPointerException on the second fragment at line: int myString  = args.getString("myStringLabel", (String defaultString));

Comment: @mvasco replace the (String defaultString) with something like: "my default string". the second argument is for replacing the output with it in case the string does not exist.

Comment: @Thank you, I have tried also with: String hola = args.getString("myStringLabel"); and same exception.. and String hola = args.getString("myStringLabel", "otro valor"); and same exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91050/discussion-between-saeed-entezari-and-mvasco).

Answer (score 0):

try following for replace fragment.

```
        Products_Fragment df = new Products_Fragment();//this is your fragment.
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, df);
        ft.commit();
```