# How to replace a custom fragment with another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know this question has been asked before in other threads like this one :
[Trying to replace one fragment with another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836590/trying-to-replace-one-fragment-with-another)

But, in these cases the layout file would have a  node with an id. In my case, I created a custom SettingsFragment and this SettingsFragment consists of many items. When I click on one item, it will start another fragment CreatePasswordFragment.

Now, my SettingsFragment does not have an id (or does it? I am a newbie to android....), so I don't know how to use `.replace(R.id.fragment_container,CreatePasswordFragment.newInstance())`

So far, I have used the following method, and while it works I am wondering if there is a better way to do it?

```
getActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .remove(SettingsFragment.this)
            .replace((android.R.id.content, CreatePasswordFragment.newInstance(userProfile.email))
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

The id in the `replace()` method is the container id, not your fragment id. So it would be the id of whatever layout in your activity is displaying the fragment. So you are doing it right. One thing to note, however, is that you do not need to call `remove()`. You can just call `replace()` and the `FragmentManager` will automatically call `remove()` for you.